# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in Java With Grails

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I´m getting an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` error in Google chrome when executing this code.
I want to calculate the number of values in `edades` that are between `min` and `max.

```
function edades(int min, int max){

    var edades = [22,27,29];

    var num=0; 

    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < edades.length; i++) {
        if(min<=edades[i] && edades[i]<=max){
            num++;
        }
    }

    return num;
}//edades
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the **int** type from the function arguments:

```
function edades(min, max){

    var edades = [22,27,29];

    var num=0; 

    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < edades.length; i++) {
        if(min<=edades[i] && edades[i]<=max){
            num++;
        }
    }

    return num;
}//edades
```